# How does XeTeX typeset (math) symbols which are input as unicode?

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, unicode

I'm considering moving to Xe(La)TeX for the main reason that it allows me to use unicode in my LaTeX code, making said code easier to read, especially the math.

But I'm confused on how XeTeX typesets symbols based on my input. I see three possibilities:

1. Unicode chars are made active and XeTeX outputs the TeX symbols we know and trust.
2. Unicode chars are piped (directly) through to the final (pdf, ps, dvi) document.
3. A combination of the two.

With one of the advertised points of XeTeX being direct access to system UTF-8 fonts, I'm guessing (2) has a lot to do with it.

**Beautiful Typesetting**

But TeX has always been about beautiful typesetting, and a lot of effort has gone into making symbols and their spacing look good. Do we still get the same benefits with unicode output? (Do the symbols look the same? Nicer? Worse?) I believe some symbols do not come directly from a font, but have been painstakingly crafted in TeX itself.

**Specifics**

There are specific math constructs that get special treatment in TeX but also have unicode symbols. For example, for `\cap` and `\bigcap` there are respectively ∩ and ⋂. Do they both behave accordingly? What about √? Or are there packages that implement this sort of thing?

Are most unicode math symbols interpreted correctly with regard to math spacing? (`\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, `\mathop`, `\mathopen`, `\mathclose`)

Do math delimiters derived from unicode ⦃⦄ ⦅⦆ scale vertically as they should?

Are [Combining Diacritical Marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character#Unicode_ranges) handled appropriately?

**Portability**

Will the output be different when the code is compiled on different systems? Will my generated pdf/ps/dvi look different when viewed on different systems? Or are all relevant fonts automatically included?

**`unicode-math`**

Finally, what role does `unicode-math` play in this story?

Comment: The [`alttex` package](https://github.com/alt/alttex) might be of interest to you. I’ve never used it, but it seems to aim at more Unicode-y input for XeTeX.

Comment: @doncherry I browsed through the documentation. I like the idea of `alttex` a lot, but it is clearly not ready for serious use and the author seems to agree. I might have a look at the code, though, when I'm not so busy. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XeTeX introduced new primitives such as `\Umathcode` (up to version 0.9998 called `\XeTeXmathcode`, renamed for compatibility with LuaTeX) that's the Unicode analog of `\mathcode`.

What does `\mathcode` in traditional TeX? A declaration such as

```
\mathcode`+="202B
```

tells TeX that a `+` in math mode should be treated as a binary operation symbol (leftmost byte `"2`), taken from font family `"0` and slot `"2B` in the corresponding font. In the same vein, one can say something like

```
\Umathcode`∑="1 "1 "2211
```

or even

```
\Umathcode`∑="1 "1 `∑
```

The primitive `\Umathcode` has the syntax

```
\Umathcode<Unicode point> = <math type> <family> <slot>
```

After the (optional) `=`, three numbers should be given, because packing the information into a single number as done by TeX is not possible. Actually the information is still packed into a single number (in this case it's decimal 18883089, hexadecimal `"1202211`), but the translation from packed number to explicit type-family-slot is not straightforward.

This will be probably accompanied by a similar declaration

```
\Umathchardef\sum="1 "1 "2211
```

so that typing `$∑$` or `$\sum$` will give the same result.

The `unicode-math` package loads a huge list of symbols and performs assignments similar to the one for `∑`. The number corresponding to `∑` will be different, because it depends on many aspects which can't be covered in a short answer.

Actually `unicode-math` does much more than this, because it sets things up so that commands such as `\mathbf` or `\mathrm` give the desired result.

There are other primitives corresponding to the traditional ones, namely `\Umathchar`, for using a directly specified character, or `\Udelimiter` for setting delimiters with normal and large variant, `\Umathaccent` and finally `\Uradical` for defining root symbols. See [`texdoc xetex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xetex/xetexref/XeTeX-reference.pdf) that will open  “The XeTeX reference guide” by Will Robertson and Khaled Hosny.

Answer (score 4):

Unicode maths is typeset in concert with an OpenType `MATH` table that is present in the font; this table contains data equivalent to the `\fontdimen`s of a traditional TeX maths font; see [this TUGboat article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94vieth.pdf). Thus the spacing is the same as it ever was. These fonts contain glyphs for symbols at various sizes and the appropriate ones are used automatically by the font. The fonts are embedded in the PDF file. The glyphs appear in the file as Unicode characters. The `unicode-math` package provides support for using the traditional TeX control sequences for maths symbols and constructs, and a simple interface for loading OpenType maths fonts.

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't need xetex for (1); in principle `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` would allow utf8 input to work with classic TeX (but may require quite a few more commands defining than the default setup if you wanted it to cover the math range)

Not (3) as it mostly doesn't use active characters.

Not really (directly) (2) either.

Mostly it works the same way as classic TeX: in math mode every character has a `\mathcode` that tells TeX what font and slot to use, and whether the symbol is a relation etc. xetex (and luatex) are conceptually the same except the mathcode table is enlarged so any unicode codepoint can have a mathcode not just values up to hex FF. So the mapping is not "straight through" but not implemented via active characters.

Then there are all the details the package has to get right such as mapping traditional commands such as `\mathbf` from working by switching character range within the same font instead of switching fonts, and getting the math typesetting parameters from the opentype tables instead of tfm files.